# How to centre content

Tags: html, css

How can I CENTRE the entire article content (text should stay as left-aligned)? Thank you! (I'm using Wordpress Theme and stuck as to how to go about fixing this. I'm a beginner coder.)

Comment: Put them both in one and the same wrapper `div` and set the css for that div to `text-align: center;`?  Btw., personally I kinda like it as it is now.

Comment: can you post the screen shot, or at least some codes?

Comment: the problem is in `container` CSS. it has both `width:80%` and margin-left:auto / margin-right:auto.

margin-left and margin-right are correct - they make sure the entire div is centered. however the width is skewing the contents. you might want to create a new CSS class name and give it a different width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to .row -

```
.row {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a fixed width to the `primary` element and add `margin: 0 auto;`, so it'll be centered. For example:

Change your content area html from:

```html
<div id="primary" class="content-area col-md-9"></div>
```

to:

```html
<div id="primary" class="content-area centered"></div>
```

and add a css:

```css
.content-area.centered {
  max-width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem lies in this CSS rule. To fix it just set the padding to 0px. This specific CSS rule is probably in style.css file of this theme.

```css
.page .page-wrap .content-wrapper, .single .page-wrap .content-wrapper {
    // padding: 30px; (before)
    padding: 0px; // fixed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress supports Bootstrap. Try this:

```
<div class="col-lg-3"></div>
<div class="col-lg-6" style="text-align: left;">

<!-- YOUR ARTICLE HERE -->

</div>
<div class="col-lg-3"></div>
```

I hope you got it right..